# Trying to find test and training errors for ridge regression as a function of sample size

Tags: r, regression, prediction, training-data, glmnet

I am using the Hitters dataset in R. Currently I fit a linear regression predicting Salary from all other covariates with varying sample sizes from 20 to 75 and I calculated the average test/training errors :

```
data("Hitters", package = 'ISLR')
Hitters = na.omit(Hitters)
set.seed(1)
train.idx = sample(1:nrow(Hitters), 75,replace=FALSE)
train = Hitters[train.idx,-20]
test = Hitters[-train.idx,-20]

errs <- rep(NA,56)
for (ii in 20:75){
  train.idx = sample(1:nrow(Hitters), ii,replace=FALSE)
  train = Hitters[train.idx,-20]
  test = Hitters[-train.idx,-20]
  train.lm <- lm(Salary ~., - Salary, data = train)
  train.pred <- predict(train.lm, train)
  test.pred <- predict(train.lm, data = test)
  errs[ii-19] <-  mean((test.pred - train$Salary)^2)
}
errs
```

Now I am trying to do the same with Ridge regression using those samples I created from before with a regularization parameter of 20. I tried:

```
x_train = model.matrix(Salary~., train)[,-1]
x_test = model.matrix(Salary~., test)[,-1]

y_train = train$Salary
y_test = test$Salary

#cv.out = cv.glmnet(x_train,y_train, alpha = 0)
#lam = cv.out$lambda.min


errs.train <- rep(NA, 56)
for (ii in 20:75){
  ridge_mod = glmnet(x_train, y_train, alpha=0, lambda = 20)
  ridge_pred = predict(ridge_mod, newx = x_test)
  #errs.test[ii] <- mean((ridge_pred - y_test)^2)
  errs.train[ii-19] <- mean((ridge_pred - y_train)^2)
}

errs.train
```

But all the errors are coming out the same. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you look at the first snippet, `sample` is being used in the `for` loop. In your second snippet, there is no sampling, so you are not changing anything with the data in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few bugs in the first part of the code for `lm`. It should be `predict(train.lm, newdata = test)` instead of `predict(train.lm, data = test)` . Do `?predict.lm` if you are not sure of the input. Second, if you are interested in the error in test set, you should be subtracting the prediction of `test` with `test$Salary` and with the values from `train` . Something like below should work:

```
data("Hitters", package = 'ISLR')
Hitters = na.omit(Hitters)
set.seed(1)

sample_size = 20:75
errs = vector("numeric",length(sample_size))
for (ii in seq_along(sample_size)){
  train.idx = sample(1:nrow(Hitters), sample_size[ii],replace=FALSE)
  train = Hitters[train.idx,-20]
  test = Hitters[-train.idx,-20]
  train.lm <- lm(Salary ~., data = train)
  test.pred <- predict(train.lm, newdata = test)
  errs[ii] <-  mean((test.pred - test$Salary)^2)
}
```

Now for ridge, only difference is that you create the model matrix and subset with each iteration :

```
errs.test = vector("numeric",length(sample_size))

x_data = model.matrix(Salary~., Hitters)[,-1]
y_data = Hitters$Salary

for (ii in seq_along(sample_size)){

  train.idx = sample(1:nrow(x_data), sample_size[ii],replace=FALSE)

  x_train = x_data[train.idx,]
  x_test = x_data[-train.idx,]
  y_train = y_data[train.idx]
  y_test = y_data[-train.idx]

  ridge_mod = glmnet(x_train, y_train, alpha=0, lambda = 20)
  ridge_pred = predict(ridge_mod, newx = x_test)

  errs.test[ii] <- mean((ridge_pred - y_test)^2)
}
```